# How to loop through each point of a multi point selection to get the pixel value?

Tags: imagej, fiji, imagej-macro

I'm new to ImageJ and ImageJ macro. I started to make a macro that apply the "Find Maxima" function on an image. Then I would like to test each pixel spotted as maxima to filter them by value. How can I loop through all the points of the selection into my macro ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer :

```
threshold = 254;

getSelectionCoordinates(x, y);
     for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        if(getPixel(x[i], y[i]) < threshold){
            setKeyDown("alt");
            makePoint(x[i], y[i]);
        }
```